# XML to String works propertly on one database, but not on second

Tags: java, xml, database, oracle, oracle10g

I have strange situation - I have java stored procedure to generate XML, and to store it in `String`. Generation XML to `Document` works, but problem occurs when I try to convert it to `String`. This

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

works without problems on one database (generating and transform), but on the other one everything seems to be ok with XML, but it looks like `transformer.transform(source, result);` doesnt work (`sw.lenght` is 0). I don't know what happend to this second DB, perhaps somebody was doing something with java classes (even with aurora classes).

It's Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.

My question can be a bit chaotic, so fell free to ask me for details.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "try to print it", do you mean you want to print it to `System.out`?

Comment: No, I used it as a synonym to "write it to string" - sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Problem lies in java classes. What I was supposed to do was export java classes, java sources and java resources via datapump from other database (not even from `SYS` scheme) and - in this incorrectly working database - delete all this stuff (for particular scheme) and load dmp file.
Finally, everything works fine. 
I have no idea why classes was problematic, but now I know how to solve this ;)